# Image won't auto-load after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, prettyphoto

I have a question regarding prettyphoto. So i have five thumbnails on the page on a click on one of them my jquery ajax request launches and after it finishes to load the photos on the page i would like the image to automatically open but it does not it just updates my thumbnails and i have to click again on a thumbnail.does anyone have any idea on how i could do that ?
her is my ajax code

```
function ajaxcall(inf) {
   var url= 'galerie.action';
   var data = {data : inf};
   var div=inf;
     $.get(url,data, function(raspuns){
          $('#galerie'+div).html(raspuns);
     });
 };
```

here is the code behind a thumbnail :

and here is the output code:

```
<div id="galerie1" class="ngg-gallery-galerie1">
            <div id="ngg-image-01" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
                    <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
                    <a window.onload="getName()" rel="prettyPhoto[set_1]" href="/daitoart/userfiles/images/inside/galerie/1/Jeep Tours-7day1-6-Brasov-Rasnov Fort.jpg" alt=""><br>
                    </a></div></div></div>







                <div id="ngg-image-01" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
                <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
                <a window.onload="getName()" rel="prettyPhoto[set_1]" href="/daitoart/userfiles/images/inside/galerie/1/Jeep Tours-7day1-7-Brasov-center.jpg" alt=""><br>
                </a></div></div>
```

Comment: this is just function can you show me where you fire it?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with this code, what is the code you use to have the image open automatically? I think that code might have been added to all other images, but not to the ones you are adding dynamically, because the functions were binded to the other images on document.load

Comment: there is no problem with the code i just want to know how to open the image automatically because i cant't get it to do this i read something about the jquery.click but i can't get it to work hence i would have to pass the a tag id dynamically

Comment: @Berker Yüceer: i added all the code.....

Comment: @user1660324 try `$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").click(function() { changepicturecallback: function(){ initialize(); }`

Comment: also check out for `$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").click(function() { ajaxcallback: myfunction() { //do your call here.. } });` its all about call state.

Comment: it doesn't work.....in fact it crashes my ajax request...